# Java- Allow one thread to update a value, others to wait and skip critical section

Tags: java, multithreading, locking, mutex, semaphore

Hi I have a situation in which I have to allow only one thread to say update a variable.

There is a trigger, which might invoke multiple threads to update this variable, however the update should happen only once by the first thread whichever arrives at the critical section.

Ideally the flow should be like follows:

Thread-1; Thread-2 and Thread-3 are invoked to update a variable in critical section guarded by a lock or a mutex

Critical section using this guard allows only one thread to enter, Thread-2 and Thread-3 wait just outside.

Once this variable is updated by Thread-1; Thread-2 and Thread-3 resume with other work without causing an effect on the variable.

I have come up with the following implementation, but I am not able to make other threads wait and skip updation:

```
public class Main {


    private static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main m = new Main();

        new Thread(m::doSomeOperation).start();

        new Thread(m::doSomeOperation).start();

        new Thread(m::doSomeOperation).start();


    }


    private void doSomeOperation() {

    try {
        System.out.println("Thread about to acquire lock: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        if (lock.tryLock()) {
            System.out.println("Lock held by " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + lock.isHeldByCurrentThread());
            counter++;
            // Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.out.println("Counter value: " + counter + " worked by thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (lock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
            lock.unlock();
            System.out.println("Unlocked: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }


}
}
```

At the end, the counter value is 3, I want counter value to be one also I want other threads to wait till the first thread updates the counter. Ideas appreciated. I would prefer a solution using locks / mutex rather than wait and notify.

Output:

```
Thread about to acquire lock: Thread-0
Lock held by Thread-0 true
Thread about to acquire lock: Thread-1
Counter value: 1 worked by thread Thread-0
Unlocked: Thread-0
Thread about to acquire lock: Thread-2
Lock held by Thread-2 true
Counter value: 2 worked by thread Thread-2
Unlocked: Thread-2

Process finished with exit code 0
```

**Note**
*My use case, is different - the example of updating a counter is for simplicity sake. Actually I am updating a session token in the doSomeOperation method.*

Comment: `if (lock.tryLock()) { counter++; }`.

Comment: I have the following oputput if I use if(lock.tryLock)
`Thread about to acquire lock: Thread-0
Lock held by Thread-0 true
Thread about to acquire lock: Thread-1
Counter value: 1 worked by thread Thread-0
Unlocked: Thread-1
Unlocked: Thread-0
Thread about to acquire lock: Thread-2
Lock held by Thread-2 true
Counter value: 2 worked by thread Thread-2
Unlocked: Thread-2`

Comment: The counter seems to be updated twice - still.

Comment: You want a single variable to check if something did already enter the critical section.

Comment: I cannot rely on a variable, this operation might have to be done again at a later time, in which case this variable will not allow updation by a new set of threads. Or I will have to carry an overhead of creating this class multiple times.

Comment: I said, you want a flag that is checked if the critical section has already been entered.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `AtomicInteger` here and forgo with worrying about formal locks:

```
public class Worker {
    private static AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);

    private void doSomeOperation() {
        counter.incrementAndGet();
        System.out.println("Counter value: " + counter + " worked by thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Worker w = new Worker();
        new Thread(w::doSomeOperation).start();
        new Thread(w::doSomeOperation).start();
        new Thread(w::doSomeOperation).start();
    }
}
```

Comment: My use case, is different - the example of updating a counter is for simplicity sake. Actually I am updating a session token in the doSomeOperation method. 
having said that, the output of above is: 
`Counter value: 0 worked by thread Thread-0
Counter value: 0 worked by thread Thread-1
Counter value: 0 worked by thread Thread-2`

Comment: @User3 Sorry...what I had there originally would compile and run, but not reflect your problem.  Try making the `AtomicInteger` _static_, to simulate a single shared resource.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference, the method is called from main() no new instance of the class is created. With static, the output is still same. Check here: http://ideone.com/mcvC2k

Comment: @User3 you made a typo in the end of your code when you mixed `counterx` and `counter`.

Comment: Oh, my bad..! Here is the new output: 

`Counter value: 1 worked by thread Thread-0
Counter value: 2 worked by thread Thread-1
Counter value: 3 worked by thread Thread-2`

Answer (score 1):

Problem is occurring  because Initially one thread increases the counter and release the lock and  your program is running so fast that, once first thread releases the lock then another thread enters the method and it sees the lock free so it acquires the lock and increase the counter further. You can make use of `countDownLatch` in this case.

Here one thread which get the lock decrease the latch count by one and makes it zero, after that none of the thread will be able to process because 
`latch.getCount()==1` condition will fail.

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Test2 {


    private static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private static CountDownLatch latch= new CountDownLatch(1);
    private int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test2 m = new Test2();

        new Thread(m::doSomeOperation).start();

        new Thread(m::doSomeOperation).start();

        new Thread(m::doSomeOperation).start();


    }


    private void doSomeOperation() {

    try {
        System.out.println("Thread about to acquire lock: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        if (lock.tryLock() && latch.getCount()==1) {
            System.out.println("Lock held by " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + lock.isHeldByCurrentThread());
            counter++;
            latch.countDown();
             Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.out.println("Counter value: " + counter + " worked by thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        System.out.println("Exiting" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (lock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
            lock.unlock();
            System.out.println("Unlocked: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }


}
}
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class Test2 {


    private static ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private static CountDownLatch latch= new CountDownLatch(1);
    private int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test2 m = new Test2();

        new Thread(m::doSomeOperation).start();

        new Thread(m::doSomeOperation).start();

        new Thread(m::doSomeOperation).start();


    }


    private void doSomeOperation() {

    try {
        System.out.println("Thread about to acquire lock: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        if (lock.tryLock() && latch.getCount()==1) {
            System.out.println("Lock held by " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + lock.isHeldByCurrentThread());
            counter++;
            latch.countDown();
             Thread.sleep(3000);
            System.out.println("Counter value: " + counter + " worked by thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        System.out.println("Exiting" + Thread.currentThread().getName());

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (lock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
            lock.unlock();
            System.out.println("Unlocked: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    }


}
}
```

Comment: This seems ideal, however there is one catch which I can see here - say I want to do this operation again after x amount of time or when the trigger hits again, in that case the latch will not allow any thread to enter.

Comment: Hmm.. in that case will it be possible to initilize the latch count everyTime a trigger occurs?

Comment: Nope, events are triggered at random by network calls.

Comment: and for every event triggered you are creating a new thread?any certain interval min or max ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. For every event - rather for each network call a thread is created. Sometimes these calls might be parallel sometimes they might be one after the other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200155/discussion-between-nawnit-sen-and-user3).

Answer (score 0):

If you know the exact number of threads you starts each round:
You can do it like this:

```
 private int threadCounter;
 private int threadCount = 3;
    private void doSomeOperation() {

        try {
            System.out.println("Thread about to acquire lock: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            if (lock.tryLock()) {
                System.out.println("Lock held by " + Thread.currentThread().getName() + " " + lock.isHeldByCurrentThread());
                if (threadCounter++ % threadCount == 0) {
                    counter++;
                    // Thread.sleep(3000);
                    System.out.println("Counter value: " + counter + " worked by thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (lock.isHeldByCurrentThread()) {
                lock.unlock();
                System.out.println("Unlocked: " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            }
        }

    }
```

It will allow to increment counter only to the the first thread in each round.

Comment: Threads are triggered by an event, this event can trigger any number of threads. Which can be sequential or parallel, no way I can get to know the number of threads at the start,

Answer (score 0):

The Java concurrency utils don't seem to offer something exactly like what you (and me) need. But here's a relatively simple approach.

```
public class Sample {

    private String token;

    public String getToken(boolean forceNew) {
        boolean expired = false; // would be replace with actual check
        if (expired) {
            return getNewAccessToken();
        } else {
            return token;
        }
    }

    private String getNewAccessToken() {
        String currentToken = token; // Get current token
        synchronized (currentToken) { // Semaphore on the current token
            if (currentToken != token) // Now check if it changed after obtaining the lock
                return token; // If so, it has just been renewed and we don't need another exchange
            // Otherwise do the renew
            Response response = null;
            // Token fetch/refresh code here...
            // response = result of some call
            processResponse(response);
            return token;
        }
    }

    private void processResponse(Response response) {
        token = "test"; // in reality get the value from the response
    }

}
```

Suppose thread A and B arrive at `getNewAccessToken()` simultaneously. Following conditions are possible:

- Thread A assigns the `token` field to local variable `currentToken`. Thread B does the same in its invocation. Now thread A enters the synchronized block. Thread B has to wait. Thread A renews the token and exits the synchronized block. Thread B can now enter but the `token` field is no longer the same object as the `currentToken` variable, so it just returns.
- Thread A assigns the `token` field to local variable `currentToken` and enters the synchronized block. Only now does thread B assign the `token` field to local variable `currentToken`. Thread B has to wait until A exits the synchronized block before it can proceed. There's two possiblities here:

  - Thread A had already finished the renewal and invoked `processResponse` before thread B assigned `token` to `currentToken`. Thread B will then do an unnecessary refresh because currentToken == token. In fact it won't have to wait for the synchronization because A and B are locked onto a different object (A on the old token, B on the new one).
  - Thread A is still in the process of renewing the token. Thread B will not do an unnecessary refresh because currentToken != token once it gets into the synchronized block.
- Any other order is easily proven to be a mirror image of the above.

The situation is not 100% waterproof because there are still situations where an unnecessary renewal is done for concurrent threads. But this would not occur during the part of the process that takes the longest, the actual renewal of the token via some network call. After that there isn't really any difference between the scenario where we just happen to hit the narrow window between thread A having finished the network call and updating the field while thread B enters, of thread B just coming in after A is entirely done.

If you want to refine this to avoid unnecessary updates you could also look at some expiration info from the response or keep a timestamp of the last renewal and block new ones within too short a time frame.