# Allow one thread to update a value (refresh an auth token), others to wait and skip critical section

Tags: multithreading, go, mutex, condition-variable

I am sending HTTP requests from multiple threads to multiple destinations. These requests need authorization. I have a single authorization server from where I get the authorization token.

So, when the authorization token expires (i.e. HTTP response status 401) I would like one of the threads to go and refresh the token while other threads wait. When the token is refreshed all the threads should continue sending requests without attempting to refresh the token again.

Here is my implementation:

```
type httpSenderAgent struct {
    // irrelevant members omited
    ...
    client *http.Client
    tokenState int // (valid = 1, expired = 0)
    token string
    cond sync.Cond
}
```

```
func (a *httpSenderAgent) send(url string, body interface{}, retrycount int) error {

    if retrycount >= MAX_AUTH_RETRY {
        return errors.New("Max retry exceeded")
    }

    buf := &bytes.Buffer{}
    json.NewEncoder(buf).Encode(body)
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, buf)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
    req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Bearer "+a.token)

    res, err := a.client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    defer res.Body.Close()

    if res.StatusCode == http.StatusUnauthorized {
        a.refreshAuthToken()
        return a.send(url , body, retrycount + 1)
    }

    if res.StatusCode < 200 || res.StatusCode > 299 {
        return errors.New(http.StatusText(res.StatusCode))
    }

    return nil
}
```

```
func (a *httpSenderAgent) refreshAuthToken() {
    // lock section 1
    a.cond.L.Lock()
    if a.tokenState == valid {
        a.tokenState = expired
        go func() {
            // getAuthToken() is a http call to auth server
            tkn := a.getAuthToken()


            // lock section 2
            a.cond.L.Lock()
            a.token = tkn
            a.tokenState = valid
            a.cond.L.Unlock()

            a.cond.Broadcast()
        }()
    }

    for a.tokenState != valid {
        a.cond.Wait()
    }
    a.cond.L.Unlock()
}
```

but, the problem arises in following situation:

Let's say the first thread gets 401 response, it makes `tokenState` expired, starts a goroutine to fetch token and waits for the token to be valid, In the meantime, another thread gets 401 and calls `refreshAuthToken()`. By this time the token fetching thread enters `lock section 2`. So, the second thread can't enter `lock section 1` it waits for the mutex to be unlocked. When token fetching thread updates the `tokenState` to valid and unlocks the mutex, the second thread will lock the mutex and find that the token is valid. So, it will repeat the whole token fetching process.

I have checked out the SO question with same title [Java- Allow one thread to update a value, others to wait and skip critical section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58164463/java-allow-one-thread-to-update-a-value-others-to-wait-and-skip-critical-secti). But, answers do not cover my use case.

So, how can I change this to fetch the auth token only once until expired again? What synchronization primitive should I use to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not sure how you envision a `sync.Cond` working here, but it sounds like you're looking to do something that [singleflight](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/singleflight) could handle

Comment: Do you have any way to know when it would expire, or cheaply check if it has expired? That would make a big difference in the complexity of the solution.

Comment: @JimB singleflight seems interesting, I will give it a try. But, synchronization of the `forget()` function call may lead to the same situation.
Other than `sync.Cond` which synchronization primitive would you suggest in such situations?

Comment: @Adrian, could make use of expiry time. But, this may not be the case always (when the token is encrypted).

Comment: I concur with @Adrian. I've use a similar technique when dealing with MS's Graph API. The auth token is one-hour (indicated in the auth response). The client api get the mutex protected token to do their work. A service go-routine performs a re-auth 5-minutes prior to expiration - mutex swapping in new token when done. Client api's see no interruption in service during these reauth windows.

Comment: the above assumes you're ok with continuous auth token coverage - even if no client api calls are being triggered to need an active auth token. But if this is the case, then it's better left to a service go-routine - and not both with complex client logic trigger the token refreshes.

Comment: @colminator not necessarily. The update can be triggered by a client trying to get the token, and if it's expired, it makes the client wait for it to get a new token.

Comment: @Adrian true, depends on what makes sense for the app over a 24/7 period. The key is not to over complicate the mutex logic e.g. don't hold the lock prior to a REST call, but instead only when you're ready to swap in the renewed token.